# Why is my BootBox seemingly inaccessable?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootbox

I can't seem to access any of the elements from my bootbox.  I've tried renaming all the fields, but it won't validate and it won't give me a value:

[image]

My **BootBox** code including some debugging attempts:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnNew", function () {
    //$("#btnNew").click(function () {
        var form = $("#newSubjectCard").html();
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: form,
            title: "Add New Subject",
            buttons: {
                close: {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    className: "btn btn-sm btn-danger",
                    callback: function () { }
                },
                success: {
                    label: "Add Subject",
                    className: "btn btn-sm btn-primary",
                    callback: function () {
                        if ($("#newSubjectName").val() == "" || $("#newSubjectEmail").val() == "") {
                            console.log($("#newSubjectName").val());
                            console.log($("#newSubjectEmail").val());
                            console.log("Fail");
                            
                            return false;  // keeps dialog open
                        } else {
                            //addCustomer();
                            console.log($("#newSubjectName").val());
                            console.log($("#newSubjectEmail").val());
                            //console.log("tried to submit");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#addCustomer").validate({
            // Specify validation rules
            rules: {
                newSubjectName: "required",
                newSubjectEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                newSubjectName: "Please enter a name",
                newSubjectEmail: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                console.log("submitted");
            }
        });
    //});
})
```

My **Form**:

```
<div id="newSubjectCard" class="d-none">
    <form id="addCustomer">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                Name:
                <input type="text" id="newSubjectName" name="newSubjectName" class="form-control" placeholder="JANE DOE">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                Email:
                <input type="text" id="newSubjectEmail" name="newSubjectEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="JANE.DOE@GMAIL.COM">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                Group:
                <input type="text" id="newSubjectGroup" name="newSubjectGroup" class="form-control" placeholder="MR. JOHNS CLASS">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've been staring at this screen so long I feel like my eyes are going to pop out.  Thanks in advance!

**** **EDIT** ****
To solve, I moved my form code directly to JS so that it wouldn't be duplicated.  Thank you all for the help!:

```
var form = `<div id="newSubjectCard">
                            <form id="addCustomer">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        Name:
                                        <input type="text" id="newSubjectName" name="newSubjectName" class="form-control" placeholder="JANE DOE">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        Email:
                                        <input type="text" id="newSubjectEmail" name="newSubjectEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="JANE.DOE@GMAIL.COM">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        Group:
                                        <input type="text" id="newSubjectGroup" name="newSubjectGroup" class="form-control" placeholder="MR. JOHNS CLASS">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>`;
            bootbox.dialog({
                message: form,
                title: "Add New Subject",
                buttons: {
                    close: {
                        label: 'Cancel',
                        className: "btn btn-sm btn-danger",
                        callback: function () { }
                    },
                    success: {
                        label: "Add Subject",
                        className: "btn btn-sm btn-primary",
                        callback: function () {
                            if ($("#newSubjectName").val() == "" || $("#newSubjectEmail").val() == "") {
                                console.log($("#newSubjectName").val());
                                console.log($("#newSubjectEmail").val());
                                console.log("Fail");
                                $("#addCustomer").valid;

                                return false;  // keeps dialog open

                            } else {
                                //addCustomer();
                                console.log($("#newSubjectName").val());
                                console.log($("#newSubjectEmail").val());
                                //console.log("tried to submit");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I believe that, due to the way you're using bootbox, you have duplicate elements. There's the ones from the template you have in your html and then the ones from the copy you make to pass to bootbox to show in the dialog. Either duplicate IDs are breaking things or the values are coming from the template instead of the dialog.

Comment: @Ouroborus - You were correct.  The thing that blows my mind, is that I copied most of this code from another section of my application and it works find over there.  I pasted the HTML between 2 backticks and assigned it directly to the form var.  Works now.  Thanks!

Comment: .. Ahh, my original code worked because the form ID was dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you keep getting null input values is that you using bootbox and your input element is created inside of bootbox so you have to define your input element in jquery like this

```
$('<your jquery selector for input>','.bootbox').val()
```

here is a working demo hope it will help you to clear bootbox input element null issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.5.2/bootbox.min.js" integrity="sha512-RdSPYh1WA6BF0RhpisYJVYkOyTzK4HwofJ3Q7ivt/jkpW6Vc8AurL1R+4AUcvn9IwEKAPm/fk7qFZW3OuiUDeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#btnNew", function () {
debugger
    //$("#btnNew").click(function () {
        var form = $("#newSubjectCard").html();
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: form,
            title: "Add New Subject",
            buttons: {
                close: {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    className: "btn btn-sm btn-danger",
                    callback: function () { }
                },
                success: {
                    label: "Add Subject",
                    className: "btn btn-sm btn-primary",
                    callback: function () {
                    debugger
                        if ($("#newSubjectName",".bootbox").val() == "" || $("#newSubjectEmail",".bootbox").val() == "") {
                            console.log($("#newSubjectName",".bootbox").val());
                            console.log($("#newSubjectEmail",".bootbox").val());
                            console.log("Fail");
                            
                            return false;  // keeps dialog open
                        } else {
                            //addCustomer();
                            console.log($("#newSubjectName",".bootbox").val());
                            console.log($("#newSubjectEmail",".bootbox").val());
                            //console.log("tried to submit");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

  
    //});
})
 
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnNew">click</button>
<div id="newSubjectCard" class="d-none">
    <form id="addCustomer">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                Name:
                <input type="text" id="newSubjectName" name="newSubjectName" class="form-control" placeholder="JANE DOE">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                Email:
                <input type="text" id="newSubjectEmail" name="newSubjectEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="JANE.DOE@GMAIL.COM">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                Group:
                <input type="text" id="newSubjectGroup" name="newSubjectGroup" class="form-control" placeholder="MR. JOHNS CLASS">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  As it turns out, Ouroborus, was correct. The root problem was that everything was duplicated.  Your solution worked also so I will accept it as an asnwer.